# get values from input data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have input dataset in keyvalue with delimiter as below,

```
key1:value1|key2:value2|key3:value3  
key1:value4|key2:value5|key3:value6
```

i want to create a rdd/dataframe with format as

```
value1|value2|value3  
value4|value5|value6
```

i tried this using flatmap to seperate each item and map to extract values from the records, then i am getting my output as in different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map like this:

```
(rdd

    # Split by "|" and then for each item by ":"
    .map(lambda xs: [x.split(":")[1] for x in xs.split("|")])
    # Convert to tuple
    .map(tuple)
    .toDF(["key1", "key2", "key3"]))
```

Comment: what if i have some of the rows like, where some of the fields contains delimiters like -  key1:value1|key2:value2|key3:bad||value. I tried this with regex - ((?<!\^\^)\^\^(?!\^\^)) but it doesn't work.